# Enable Letsencrypt in Debian 9 with Nginx for Gogs

Tags: nginx, vps, lets-encrypt, gogs

I just installed Gogs on a VPS with the help of the tuto (https://gogs.io/docs/installation/install_from_source).
I have a sub domain to reach my gogs instance: git.mydomainname.com and it works: http://git.mydomainname.com goes to my gogs instance with a reverse proxy.

I would like to have my gogs protected through SSL, so I would like to install LetsEncrypt using the following tuto (https://certbot.eff.org/#debianstretch-nginx).

I would like to say that I am new to system administration and don't necessarily understand everything I did during the Gogs install.
I am also new to Nginx (more used to Apache).

Here is the process I followed:

```
$ sudo certbot certonly
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

How would you like to authenticate with the ACME CA?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: Place files in webroot directory (webroot)
2: Spin up a temporary webserver (standalone)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 1
Please enter in your domain name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c'
to cancel):git.mydomainname.com
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for git.mydomainname.com

Select the webroot for git.mydomainname.com:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: Enter a new webroot
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Press 1 [enter] to confirm the selection (press 'c' to cancel): /home/git/go/src/github.com/gogits/gogs

** Invalid input **
Press 1 [enter] to confirm the selection (press 'c' to cancel): 1
Input the webroot for git.mydomainname.com: (Enter 'c' to cancel):/home/git/go/src/github.com/gogits/gogs
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. git.mydomainname.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://git.mydomainname.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/N4rMGzoq1Bwyt9MP9fUlVY3_mDnJfRYpQkdvc7WrNJs: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: git.mydomainname.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://git.mydomainname.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/N4rMGzoq1Bwyt9MP9fUlVY3_mDnJfRYpQkdvc7WrNJs:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

So I checked the error, the DNS A record is OK.
I also found another tuto in french (https://www.grafikart.fr/formations/serveur-linux/nginx-ssl-letsencrypt) to help me and I noticed that I had to update my nginx config for the website, I did, despite I have a reverse proxy (maybe the issue is here).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.mydomainname.com

    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:port_number;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `2: Spin up a temporary webserver (standalone)` instead of the webroot one.

Answer (score 0):

You are proxifying all of your requests to http://localhost:port_number, but this program probably doesn't know how to handle lets-encrypt request.

Instead, you should change your .well-known location to :

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
  allow all;
  root /var/www/letsencrypt;
}
```

And when the certbot ask you for a webroot, you can answer `/var/www/letsencrypt`

Note: you can change `/var/www/letsencrypt` to any directory you want. It just need to be created first, and readable by your nginx's user